# queries in php, cannot find the correct value

Tags: date, sum, orders

I have a "shop" script and i want to show the income values from the sql database but i dont know what im doing wrong cuz i get both at the same value :(

```
<?php 
$x = date('d'); 
$res = $db->query("SELECT sum(amount) FROM orders WHERE SUBSTRING(date,6,2) = '$x' AND address != 'NONE' AND method='Bitcoin' OR method='PerfectMoney'"); 
$cols = $res->fetch_row(); 
echo "$".$cols[0]; 
?>

<?php 
$mth = date('m'); 
$res = $db->query("SELECT sum(amount) FROM orders WHERE SUBSTRING(date,9,2) = '$mth' AND address != 'NONE' AND method='Bitcoin' OR method='PerfectMoney'"); 
$cols = $res->fetch_row(); 
echo "$".$cols[0]; 
?>
```

This is the code
Where could the problem be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i figured out this one my self :(

```
SUBSTRING(date,6,2) = '$x'"); changed this one to 
SUBSTRING(date,9,2) = '$x'");
```

and

```
SUBSTRING(date,9,2) = '$mth'"); and this one to
SUBSTRING(date,6,2) = '$mth'");
```